# Returning an array without assign to a variable

Tags: java, arrays

Is there any way in java to return a new array without assigning it first to a variable?
Here is an example:

```
public class Data {
    private int a;
    private int b;
    private int c;
    private int d;
    public int[] getData() {
        int[] data = { a, b, c, d };
        return data;
    }
}
```

I want to do something like this, but doesn't work:

```
public int[] getData() {
    return {a, b, c, d};
}
```

Answer (score 133, accepted):

You still need to create the array, even if you do not assign it to a variable. Try this:

```
public int[] getData() {
    return new int[] {a,b,c,d};
}
```

Your code sample did not work because the compiler, for one thing, still needs to know what type you are attempting to create via static initialization `{}`.

Answer (score 7):

You been to construct the object that the function is returning, the following should solve your issue.

```
public int[] getData() {
    return new int[]{a,b,c,d};
}
```

hope this helps

Answer (score 3):

```
public int[] getData() {
    return new int[]{a,b,c,d};
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
return new Integer[] {a,b,c,d}; // or
return new int[] {a,b,c,d};
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public class CentsToDollars {

    public static int[] getCentsToDollars(int cents) {
        return new int[] { cents / 100, cents % 100 };
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int cents;
        System.out.print("Input the cents: ");
        cents = scan.nextInt();
        int[] result = getCentsToDollars(cents);
        System.out.println("That is " + result[0] + " dollars and " + result[1] + " cents");
        scan.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: While this might answer the authors question, it lacks some explaining words and/or links to documentation. Raw code snippets are not very helpful without some phrases around them. You may also find [how to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) very helpful. Please edit your answer - [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/21429930)

Comment: This appears to be just a repeat of all the other existing answers.