# Couple Sum return statement explanation and alternative method

Tags: java, hashmap

I was doing practice questions on Firecode and the question was:

Given an array of integers, find two numbers such that they sum up to a specific target.
The method coupleSum should return the indices of the two numbers in the array, where index1 must be less than index2.
Please note that the indices are not zero based, and you can assume that each input has exactly one solution. Target linear runtime and space complexity.

The solution given was:

```
public static int[] coupleSum(int[] numbers, int target) {
    HashMap<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
    for(int i=0; i < numbers.length; i++){
        int n = numbers[i];
        if(map.containsKey(n)){
            return new int[]{map.get(n), i+1};
        } else {
            map.put(target-n, i+1);
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Can you explain what

```
if(map.containsKey(n)){
                return new int[]{map.get(n), i+1};
```

is doing and perhaps provide an alternate way of writing it?

Comment: It's checking if `map` contains the key `n` (the element of `numbers`) and if it does, returning an array with the value of the map at key `n` and the index in `numbers` where it occurred plus one. What kind of "alternative" are you looking for?

Comment: Perhaps a way to write it without the return statement in that area? That would then cause the null statement at the end to be what we're returning instead.

Comment: You could set a value and `break`, I suppose, although it seems messier to me. The value of early returns is that you can stop thinking about it as soon as you see the `return` instead of figuring out where you've broken from, scan down, and see what else happens (if anything).

Comment: It is indeed messier, though the way it's written
            return new int[]{map.get(n), i+1};
seems unusual to me. Perhaps I think seeing it written without the return there would make the problem click for me more.

Comment: I'm not sure what's "unusual" about it; that's just how array literals work in Java.

Comment: Then it must be my inexperience then. I've never returned an array like that before.
I've returned arrays before, arraylists etc.
int[] arr={5,6,7,8,9}; 
return arr;
But, I don't think I've seen it written exactly like this before, which is why it's throwing me off.

Comment: Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/q/9331837/438992 will help solidify the idea.

Comment: So basically, it's creating the array, putting the values in, and returning it all in one step without needing to initialize it earlier? If so, I didn't realize you could do that.

Answer (score 0):

so to write more readable and understandable code, you may look at below snippet. the logic is same as mentioned in your question but we are just maintaining an array to store the desired result.

```
    HashMap<Integer,String> map = new HashMap<Integer,String>();
    int[] res = new int[2];
    //B=target
    for(int i=0; i<A.length; i++) {
        int key = A[i];
        int diff = B-key;
        if(!map.containsKey(key) && !map.containsKey(diff)) {
            map.put(diff, key+"_"+i);
        } else if (map.containsKey(key)) {
            String val = map.get(key);
            res[0] = Integer.parseInt(val.split("_")[1])+1;
            res[1] = i+1;
            return res;
        }
    }
    return new int[0];
```

In the code above, **value of HashMap** is combination of array element and it's respective index and **key of HashMap** is the difference.
Lets say **A[0] is 12**, value will be **12_0**